# Navigation of activities in android

Tags: android

### Hello I am trying to learn the screen navigation in android

- I am getting this error, though there are no syntax errors
- I have posted the code of relevant classes below

---

**CopperChimneyPhotos.java**

```
public class CopperChimneyPhotos extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.copper_chimney_photos);

        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PhotoButton);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent pt=new Intent(CopperChimneyPhotos.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
                startActivity(pt);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**CopperChimneyDesc.java**

```
public class CopperChimneyDesc extends Activity{

    private static String url = "http://url:7002/xxxx/";
    private static String url1 = "http://url:7002/xxxx/";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.copperchimney_desc_screen);

        //getting info from listview to display the name in TopNavigationBarCopperChimneyDescActivityName
        TextView topdisp=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarCopperChimneyDescActivityName);
        topdisp.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("CC_RES"));


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONObjParser jParser = new JSONObjParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);


        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < json1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = json1.getJSONObject(i);


                // Storing each json item in variable
                int id = c.getInt("_id");
                String TIME = c.getString("RestaurantTime");

                TimeMap.put(id, TIME);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                           // remaining code


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button BACKBUTTON=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarCopperChimneyDescActivityBackButton);
        BACKBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emp1=new Intent(CopperChimneyDesc.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(emp1);
            }
        });


        Button PHOTOBUTTON=(Button) findViewById(R.id.CopperChimneyPhotosButton);
```

Comment: What is at line 37 of `CopperChimneyDesc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added any extras here

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent pt=new Intent(CopperChimneyPhotos.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
            startActivity(pt);
```

in `CopperChimneyPhotos` so `getIntent().getExtras().getString("CC_RES"));` will return `null`.

I'm not sure where you expect that value to come from but it would need to be added to the `Intent` that starts this `Activity` so something like

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent pt=new Intent(CopperChimneyPhotos.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
            pt.putExtra("CC_RES", stringToAdd);
            startActivity(pt);
```

You also may want to check that `getIntent()` and `getExtras()` doesn't return `null` in your second class before assigning the value to something. You have `extras` when you go from `MainActivity` to `Desc` but not when you go from `Photos` to `Desc`.

Comment: Your solution worked for me ! .... i passed a string as you suggested ..... the null pointer Exception got solved ! .... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of bug in CopperChimneyDesc.java, line 37:

```
08-16 22:28:56.293: E/AndroidRuntime(360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 22:28:56.293: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at com.project.findmybuffet.CopperChimneyDesc.onCreate(CopperChimneyDesc.java:37)
```

Whichever line it is in your pasted sources, you got `NullPointerException` (aka `NPE`) there which usually means you try to use either value that is no longer existing, or some elements are not initialized.